# Best practice/pattern for custom ILoggerProvider with DbContext as target

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, scope, dbcontext

i'm trying to implement my own custom ILoggerProvider (with the logs being written to a database) to use into my applications.

I'm using `AddDbContext<DbContext>()` to inject the database context and using the `AddLogging()` method to inject the LoggerProvider, adding my custom provider through an ILoggingBuilder extension method. This way i can constructor inject both the DbContext and `ILogger<T>` into all my api controllers easily.

The only (and most troublesome) problem i'm facing right now is the scoping of those dependencies: while the DbContext is injected as a scoped dependency, the `ILogger` isn't, forcing me to pass the parameter `ServiceLifetime.Singleton` to the `AddDbContext` call. This sometimes causes problem while saving multiple logs in a short time, throwing an Exception.

Long story short, is there any common pattern to implement a scoped `ILoggerProvider` with database access?

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate DbContext in using block for example the following Logger:

```
public class DbLogger : ILogger
{
    string categoryName;
    string connectionString;
    DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext> optionsBuilder;

    // Accept connectionString or get it from somewhere else
    public DbLogger(string categoryName, string connectionString)
    {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.connectionString = connectionString;

        // Build your DbContextOptions here
        optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionstring);
    }

    public void Log(...)
    {
        using (DbContext dbContext = new DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            //TODO: Db insert statements here

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

This is not so flexible and I haven't found a way to fake it for my integration tests and use Sqlite for example but that may give you a starting point.